# No, nay, never, no more

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

A short one to celebrate an upcoming holiday.

> [image]
>
> 1. A loud, wild rover's intense passion (6)
>   2. Needlessly spent, under the influence of whiskey and beer (6)
>   3. I'm returning with gold inside a tropical island (4)
>   4. Never will be in the habit (4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A loud, wild rover's intense passion (6)

   > Fervor = F + wild "rover"
2. Needlessly spent, under the influence of whiskey and beer (6)

   > Wasted = Both meaning "needlessly spent" and "drunk
3. I'm returning with gold inside a tropical island (4)

   > Maui = M(Au)i
4. Never will be in the habit (4)

   > Wont = could also be read as won't

The filled in grid looks like this

> [image]

Comment: Except those don't fit in the grid. :)

Comment: Ahhh, all's correct but I've messed up the numbering... One second, I'll fix it.

Comment: Aw rats. I was answering just now that the whole point of the puzzle was drunken revelry had messed it up. :)

Comment: @Rubio Haha, that would certainly have fit the theme...